# Easily see what java script code called a web service

Tags: javascript, web-services, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I've had had the need to access this information quickly and sometimes and up spending lots of time digging trough code. Is there a way in chrome dev tools or any other dev tool that when you see the network activity for example the network activity in chrome dev tools that you can see the actual piece of code that generated the service call. This could make debugging much easier when troubleshooting new applications and or code that you don't remember much of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can see the call stack of the request from the **Initiator** toolbar like below.

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer thank you! It was in my face the entire time!